# Source of quote attributed to Cesar Chavez: "You are never strong enough that you don't need help."

Tags: quotes

> You are never strong enough that you don't need help.

Does anybody know when, where, or in what context Cesar Chavez said this quote?  Some Google searching implies that he said it, but none of the links I found gave any context for the quote.

Also, I apologize if this is the wrong StackExchange for this question -- I'm not quite sure where to put it.  If you have a better suggestion, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Unsourced according to https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Cesar_Chavez

Comment: Ah rats :( I wanted to put it at the beginning of the acknowledgements section of a book I'm writing, but I'd really prefer something that has a source

Comment: You might find it in [one of his speeches](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3329071-an-organizer-s-tale).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote is from an interview in 1970 between Chavez and John Moyer. The context is the end of the five year [Delano grape strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delano_grape_strike), *"the first successful organization of farm workers in the nation’s history"* in Moyer's words:

> **Moyer:** I sense that the style of life of people in the United Farm Workers Organizing Committee is very important to you. What’s going to happen to this as the union gets big? The union is gaining power.
>
> **Chavez:** Well, power is not bad. Power is what the game’s all about, but a lot depends on how the power is used. We are a long way from there. I think churches can have a lot of power. But I doubt if unions can have power to the extent that it is absolute. The forces working for the devil are not really that marshaled, and they haven’t got that much to lose, anyway. But the forces working for the employers are well organized, and they have a lot to lose. So the opposition to labor is much more — it’s like politics except that politics goes in
>   a cycle and it hits a high spot every two to four years. In labor it is constant, day in and day out. I don’t think labor unions really have that much power. I really don’t, because if they did there would not be the repressive laws against labor. What has happened is that labor has not been able to keep up with involvement in the total community. **You are never strong enough that you don’t need help.**
>
> - [*A Conversation With Cesar Chavez c.1970*](https://libraries.ucsd.edu/farmworkermovement/essays/essays/MillerArchive/037%20A%20Conversation%20with%20Cesar%20Chavez.pdf), By John Moyer

Comment: You are awesome - thanks!!! I suggest that you add this reference to en.wikiquote.org as well, as it would be beneficial to a wide audience of people interested in Cesar Chavez and his quotes.